# Scraping with python, selenium(WebDriver) and beautiful soap spotify artists names

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have been trying ti automate this task for a long time. 
So, what I would need is to gather all the main (first) artist name
from all the song in a specific Spotify playlist. Then, I would like to 
store all the names in a csv file

For sure i have  to open a a chromedriver window and use the playlist link like this

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://open.spotify.com/playlist/4FLeoROn5GT7n2tZq5XB4V?si=5wxAuFwgSPCuyjzUx9DDNw')

and then, how canI say "choose all the main artist names from all the tracks and store them in a csv'?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

While beautifulsoup is great for scraping data from websites, it counter-intuitive for services which provide an API. Spotify has a well documented API which would allow you to do this (scraping the data) with very little effort.

You can test the endpoints out [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference-beta/#category-playlists) for playlists. You will however need a secret key in order to generate a token to send requests to the API. That process is documented [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/app-settings/) and [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/)..

As for saving the data to a csv, this I'll have to leave up to another contributor as I've little to no knowledge in this regard.

Edit:

For an example of how to use the API with python you can check out one of my old projects [here](https://github.com/gazzamc/Youtifpy). It's not a perfect example but it should put you on the right road.

ps. That secret key is no longer valid and you shouldn't upload those to github. Use environment variables instead ;)

Comment: wow, this looks kind of complicated. Pretty new to programming, and I don't have much knowledge about api. should be easy anyway with beautifulsoup right? Idk, just really newbie and trying to move my firsts steps here

Comment: The issue bs is that Spotify could change the layout of its website which could potentially break your script. If they change the API they usually add a new version to prevent anything breaking in older applications. While it does seem complicated, it did to me too starting out. Once you use one API it's usually a similar process for others out there.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J_qcttfnJA) an easy to follow tutorial on using the Spotify API with python. While it isn't exactly what you want to do it will guide you through authentication and handling the JSON data you receive from the API.